# .NET IpcChannel doesn't reliably clean up properly?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, remoting, named-pipes

For some reason, after using an IpcChannel and shutting it down, sometimes the namedpipe stays open, with a thread waiting on it.  I cannot make this happen on demand in a debug environment, but it happens 5 to 10 times per day in our production environment.  The bad effect this is having is that it is stopping me from unloading the appdomain as there is a thread waiting infinitely on the named pipe (in a native method)...no frame on the callstack is in my code - it's an internal .net thread.  If I fire up process explorer and find the named pipe handle that was left open and forcefully close it then it all becomes happy again, the appdomain unloads fine.  It's possible I'm doing something wrong as I haven't worked with IpcChannels a whole lot....my server-side code is here: http://pastebin.com/f6e2583b9 if anyone wants to take a peek....this is running on fully patched Server2003/.NET 2.0.

As an ugly-ass workaround, I'm thinking I'll track every channel I create and then periodically check to make sure they shut down properly, and then on appdomain unload I'll forcefully close any pipes which are left hanging....can anyone point me in the right direction as to how I could do this?  I know the name of the pipe....but I'm not sure how to check if it's still open, or how to close any existing handles...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I've seen this before.

A similar thing can occur with IPC when the client still has the IPC channel open: The server will not be able to close and open it again because it's already in use by the client.

To get around these problems, the recommended way is to place **all** IPC server channel creation in a child `AppDomain`.
Then when you wish to shut it down, you merely perform the usual 'nice' shutdown procedures of `Close()` followed by an `AppDomain` Unload.
This will nuke any left overs.

It will remove any IPC related stuff as well as kick the client in the head for hogging the IPC channel ;)